# No route matches when routes seem to match

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to add a route that will enable me to merge two "articles" together but no matter what I try I keep getting "No route matches" when the routes do in fact seem to match.

From my view:

```
<%= label_tag(:merge_with, "Article ID:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:merge_with) %>
<%= button_to "Merge", {:controller=>'admin/articles', :action=>'merge_article'}, :method => :post %>
```

From my routes.rb:

```
match 'articles/:id/merge' => 'articles#merge_article', :via => :post, :as => 'merge_article'
```

Output from rake routes:

```
merge_article POST /articles/:id/merge(.:format) {:controller => "articles", :action => "merge_article"}
```

Message on page:

No route matches {:controller => "admin/articles", :action => "merge_article"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your route is expecting an `id`. you need to pass `:id` to the url like

```
{ :controller=>'admin/articles', :action=>'merge_article', :id => some_id }
```

or use

```
merge_article_path(some_id)
```

Comment: Cool thanks that did it. For the record I changed the view to look like this:  
`<%= button_to "Merge", :url => {:controller => 'admin/articles', :action => 'merge_article', :id => @article.id}, :method => :post %>`